Verify a solution for a recursion based probability problem and propose an alternative
Problem Statement:
A trial succeeds at probability p, where $0 < p < 1$. However, whenever the trial fails, p has a $\frac{2}{3}$ chance to be multiplied by $\frac{1}{2}$and $\frac{1}{3}$ chance to be multiplied by $2$ (to a maximum of $1$). Is it guaranteed the trial will eventually succeed given infinite tries?
My solution (I realized it is wrong after some simulations ):

The decision tree (see the picture) showing all the possible events that can occur given the current probability p:
Event 1: There's p chance that the process will end
Event 2: There's $\frac{1}{3}(1-p)$ chance that the process will continue and p will double
Event 3: There's $\frac{2}{3}(1-p)$ chance that the process will continue and p will be halved
To calculate the chance that the process will stop we need to sum all the likelihoods of all of the paths that end in the tree. We do this with the following formula derived from the tree:
$$f(p) = p + \frac{1}{3}(1-p) f(2p) + \frac{2}{3}(1-p) f(\frac{p}{2})$$
$$f(p) = p + (1-p)(\frac{1}{3} f(2p) + \frac{2}{3}f(\frac{p}{2}))$$
I'm not sure on the correctness of the following steps:

It is intuitive and seems reasonable to say that $f(x \cdot p) = x \cdot f(p) $.

$f(p) = l$,  $f(2p) = 2l$,  $f(\frac{p}{2}) = \frac{l}{2}$ or alternatively, like with limits $f(p)=f(2p)=f(\frac{p}{2})$ ( both givin the same answer in the end, but we will use the first substitution ).


$$l = p + (1-p)(\frac{1}{3} l + \frac{2}{3}l)$$
$$l = p + (1-p)l$$
$$l(1-1+p) = p$$
$$l \cdot p = p$$
$$l = 1 $$
And with this we conclude that it is guaranteed that the process will stop with infinite amount of steps.
Edit:
Perhaps we can upper bound $f(p)$ by assuming $f(2p) = 1$ and resolving the p<1 constraint.
$$l = p + (1-p)(\frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{3}l)$$
$$l = p + \frac{(1-p)}{3} + \frac{(1-p)}{3}l$$
$$l(1-\frac{(1-p)}{3}) = \frac{(2p+1)}{3}$$
$$l(\frac{(2+p)}{3}) = \frac{(2p+1)}{3}$$
$$l = \frac{2p+1}{p+2} $$
The only problems is that my experimental values for p = 0.125 are around 0.61 and this gives approximatively 0.588
Another upper bound can be $f(2p) = 1$ and $f(\frac{p}{2}) = f(p)$
which results in $x = 1$ meaning $f(p) < 1$

You seem to never use the fact that $p$ gets truncated to $1$ when it doubles and becomes greater than $1$ in your calculations. Also, $f(xp)=xf(p)$ should be wrong at least when $2p>1$.

In the end it should be just $p=pl$, right?


Yeah, i forgot to have a stopping criteria for p>=1
It should be l*p = p


I wrote 2 different python simulations, one using the recursive formula but with truncation and one that just simulates the process as described in the statement for up to 10000 iterations. Both of them give similar results which suggests that the success rate converges at some value in terms of p that is always less than 1. I will try to incorporate the truncation later and get a closed form formula in terms of p or some boundaries.

You might get a nicer recurrence if your recurrence tracks the number of times you've multiplied/divided by 2 rather than p itself. i.e. f(0) = p + (2/3)f(n-1) + (1/3)f(n+1). In general I think the recurrence would be f(n) = 2^n * p_0 + (2/3)f(n-1) + (1/3)f(n+1) where here p_0 is the initial probability. If my memory serves me correctly this is a fairly simple difference equation to solve, although I am very rusty on solving these so I could be wrong here.

Your suggestion is off to a good start! However, we need to be a little more careful how we deal with the doubling of $p$, because $2p$ might be bigger than $1$. Let $f(p)$ be the probability of succeeding eventually. We obviously have that $f(p)$ is increasing in $p$. As you point out, $$
f(p) = p + (1-p)\frac23 f(p/2)+ (1-p)\frac13f(2p)
$$
(as long as $2p\le 1$). More properly we should have (for $p\in(0,1)$):\begin{equation}\tag{$\star$}
f(p) = p + (1-p)\frac23 f(p/2)+ (1-p)\frac13f(\min(2p,1))
\end{equation}
Now, there is no reason a priori to expect $f$ to be differentiable, but if we suppose that it is for the sake of argument, when $p\le \frac12$, we would have $$
f'(p) = 1 + \frac13(1-p)f'(p/2) + \frac23(1-p)f'(2p)-\frac13f(p/2)-\frac23f(2p)
$$
which, if we take the limit as $p$ goes to $0$ and assume that $f$ is continuously differentiable, will yield $$
f'(0)=1 + \frac13f'(0) + \frac23f'(0)-\frac13f(0)-\frac23f(0)
$$
which implies $f(0)=1$, and the increasingness of $f$ would imply $f(p)=1$ for all $p$.
Since there's no guarantee for $f$ to be differentiable or even continuous, this doesn't actually give us the answer, however. In fact, it's misleading because there is a nonzero probability of failure for all $p\in[0,1)$, according to the results below. This means that $f(p)$ is not continuously differentiable at $0$. I believe that for $p$ small, $f(p)\sim 3p(-\log_2 p)$ but I don't yet have a proof of this.
Calculating $f(p)$
Note that, to calculate $f$ for any $p\in(0,1)$, we need only know the values of $f$ on $[\frac12,1)$, because ($\star$) can be rearranged to $$
f(p/2) = \frac{3(f(p)-p)}{2(1-p)}-\frac12f(\min(2p,1))
$$
or equivalently, whenever $p<\frac12$, we have $$\tag{$\star\star$}
f(p) = \frac{3(f(2p)-2p)}{2(1-2p)}-\frac12f(\min(4p,1))
$$
I derive below the following easily computable formula for $f(p)$ when $p\in[\frac12,1)$: $$
\frac1{1-f(p)}=  \begin{bmatrix}2&-1\end{bmatrix}\left( \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{3}{2(1-2^{-n}p)}&-\frac12\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{3}{2(1-2^{-(n-1)}p)}&-\frac12\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{3}{2(1-2^{-(n-2)}p)}&-\frac12\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\cdots\begin{bmatrix}\frac{3}{2(1-2^{-1}p)}&-\frac12\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{3}{2(1-p)}&-\frac12\\1&0\end{bmatrix} \right)\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}
$$
(Note: While this converges for any $p<1$, it does not converge to $\frac1{1-f(p)}$ for $p\in(0,\frac12)$.) For $p<1/2$ we can use ($\star\star$) to compute $f(p)$.
We can numerically verify the correctness of this formula:

The red line is $f(p)$ computed at $0.001,0.002,\dots,1$ with the above limit formula (approximating by taking $n$ finite instead of the limit, with $n$ varying based on $p$; smaller $p$'s require larger $n$ values to achieve the same precision.) The black dots represent the sample probability of success in at most 50 iterations, with 100 trials for each $p\in\{0.001,0.002,\dots,1\}$. As you can see from the graph, this formula for $f$ appears to be correct! Also, we can see that $f(p)<1$ for all $p<1$.
Proofs
Theorem: For $p<1$, there is a nonzero probability of failure.
Proof: Define a random process by $Y_0=p$ and $$
Y_{n+1} =\begin{cases}\frac12Y_n & \text{with probability }\frac23\\ 2Y_n & \text{with probability }\frac13\end{cases}
$$
(where the steps are each chosen independently). This is related to your process in a straightforward way: At the $n$th step, we say we succeed with probability $\min(Y_n,1)$. We declare success if we succeed for at least one $n\in\mathbb N$. This is equivalent to your process, because if we succeed at time $n$, we can ignore the rest of the sequence, whereas if we do not, we modify $p$ in the way you outline and try again (with guaranteed success if $p$ becomes greater than $1$).
Let $\xi_n$ be i.i.d. with $$
\xi_n =\begin{cases}1&\text{w.p. }\frac13\\-1&\text{w.p. }\frac23\end{cases}
$$
and define $X_n = \sum_{k=0}^n \xi_k$. We note that $$
Y_n \stackrel{d}{=} 2^{X_n}p
$$
From here, we can show in a straightforward way that as long as $p\in[0,1)$, there is a nonzero chance of failure. We note that there is a nonzero probability that $X_n$ is never positive, c.f. this question.
By the law of the iterated logarithm, the random variable $$
U = \sup\limits_{n\ge 3}\left(\frac{X_n + \frac n3}{\sqrt{n\log\log n}}\right)
$$
is finite almost surely. Since $X_n \le -\frac n 3 + U\sqrt{n\log\log n}$ for all $n\ge 3$, therefore we have $$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty Y_n \le Y_0+Y_1+Y_2+\sum_{n\ge 3} 2^{-\frac n 3 + U\sqrt{n\log\log n}} < \infty
$$
so $Y_n$ is summable almost surely.
Note that the probability of failing at the $n$th step is $1-\min(1,Y_n)$, therefore the probability of failing at all steps given $Y_n$ is $$
\prod_{n\ge 0}(1-\min(1,Y_n))
$$
Therefore we have that the probability of failure is $$
\sum_{(y_n)\in 2^{\mathbb Z} p} \left(\prod_{n\ge 0}(1-\min(1,y_n)) P((Y_n) = (y_n))\right) = \mathbb E\left[\prod_{n\ge 0}(1-\min(1,Y_n))\right]
$$
Since $Y_n$ is summable almost surely, we have that $\prod_{n\ge 0}(1-\min(1,Y_n))$ is nonzero almost surely as long as $Y_n<1$ for all $n$, which happens with nonzero probability. Therefore this expectation is positive. Q.E.D.
Lemma: There exists a unique function $g:(0,\infty)\rightarrow[0,1]$ such that the following hold:

$g(p)=0$ for $p\ge 1$
For $p\in(0,1)$, $$
g(p) = \frac23(1-p)g(p/2)+\frac13(1-p)g(2p)
$$
As $p$ approaches $0$: $$
\lim\limits_{p\rightarrow 0^+}g(p) = 1
$$
Proof: For $p\in[1/2,1)$, define $$
g_n(p) = g(2^{-n}p)
$$

Observe that for any $g_0$ defined on $[1/2,1)$, the recurrence relation gives us a unique $g$ such that satisfies conditions 1 and 2. Thus, it suffices to show that condition 3 uniquely determines $g_0(p)$.
Note that condition 3 implies $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} g_n(p) = 1$. Also, the recurrence in condition 2 can be re-written as $$
g_0(p) = \frac23(1-p)g_1(p)
$$
and for $n\ge1$ $$
g_n(p) = \frac23(1-2^{-n}p)g_{n+1}(p)+\frac13(1-2^{-n}p)g_{n-1}(p)
$$
(If we define $g_{-1}(p) = 0$, the above line also holds for $n=0$). This can be rearranged to obtain $$
g_{n+1}(p) = \frac3{2(1-2^{-n}p)}g_n(p) - \frac12 g_{n-1}(p)
$$
which holds for $n\ge 0$. Define $$
G_n(p) = \begin{bmatrix}g_n(p)\\ g_{n-1}(p)\end{bmatrix}
$$
Then we note that $G_n$ satisfies the recurrence $$
G_{n+1}(p) = \begin{bmatrix}\frac3{2(1-2^{-n}p)} & -\frac12\\1&0\end{bmatrix}G_n(p)
$$
with $G_0(p) = \begin{bmatrix}g_0(p)\\ 0\end{bmatrix}$. Define $M_n(p)=\begin{bmatrix}\frac3{2(1-2^{-n}p)} & -\frac12\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $M =\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} M_n(p)= \begin{bmatrix}\frac3{2} & -\frac12\\1&0\end{bmatrix}$. Then, we have $$
G_n(p) = M_{n-1}(p) M_{n-2}(p)\cdots M_0(p) G_0(p)
$$
If $g_0(p)$ is a function such that $g(p)$ satisfies condition 3, then we must have $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} G_n(p) = 
\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}M_{n-1}(p) M_{n-2}(p)\cdots M_0(p) G_0(p) = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$
Observing that $G_0(p) = g_0(p) \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ this yields $$
g_0(p) \left(\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}M_{n-1}(p) M_{n-2}(p)\cdots M_0(p) \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}\right) = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}
$$
Thus we must show existence and uniqueness of a function $g_0(p)$ that satisfies the above equation. Define $$
S_n(p) = M_{n-1}(p) M_{n-2}(p)\cdots M_0(p) 
$$
We claim that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} S_n(p)$ converges pointwise for all $p\in[\frac12,1)$. It suffices to show that for some two independent vectors $v,w$, $v^TS_n(p)$ and $w^TS_n(p)$ each converge. First, we show that $\begin{bmatrix}1,-1\end{bmatrix}S_n(p)$ converges to $0$. Note that $\begin{bmatrix}1,-1\end{bmatrix}M = \frac12\begin{bmatrix}1,-1\end{bmatrix}$. Then, observe (where $||{A}||_2$ represents either the Euclidean norm or the $L^2$ operator norm for matrices)\begin{eqnarray}
||{\begin{bmatrix}1,-1\end{bmatrix}S_{n+1}(p)}||_2 &=& ||{\begin{bmatrix}1,-1\end{bmatrix}M_n(p)S_{n}(p)}||_2\le ||{\begin{bmatrix}1,-1\end{bmatrix}M S_{n}(p)}||_2 + ||{\begin{bmatrix}1,-1\end{bmatrix}(M-M_n(p) S_{n}(p)}||_2\\ &\le& \frac12||{\begin{bmatrix}1,-1\end{bmatrix} S_{n}(p)}||_2 + ||{M-M_n(p)}||_2||{\begin{bmatrix}1,-1\end{bmatrix} S_{n}(p)}||_2\\
&=& \left(\frac12+||{M-M_n(p)}||_2\right)||{\begin{bmatrix}1,-1\end{bmatrix} S_{n}(p)}||_2
\end{eqnarray}
Since $||{M-M_n(p)}||_2$ goes to $0$, this implies $||{\begin{bmatrix}1,-1\end{bmatrix}S_{n+1}(p)}||_2$ goes to $0$ exponentially (the ratio of successive terms in the sequence approaches $1/2$).
Next, we show that $\begin{bmatrix}2,-1\end{bmatrix}S_{n+1}(p)$ converges, which we will do by showing that the difference between successive terms goes to $0$ exponentially. Let $$
\Delta_n(p) = \begin{bmatrix}2,-1\end{bmatrix}S_{n+1}(p) - \begin{bmatrix}2,-1\end{bmatrix}S_{n}(p)
$$
Observe that $\begin{bmatrix}2,-1\end{bmatrix} M = \begin{bmatrix}2,-1\end{bmatrix}$. We will need to compute the $L^2$ operator norm of $M$, which is the square root of the largest eigenvalue of $M^\ast M$ (where $(\cdot)^\ast$ represents the conjugate transpose.) Note $$
M^\ast M = \begin{bmatrix}\frac3{2} & 1\\-\frac12&0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\frac3{2} & -\frac12\\1&0\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{13}{4} & -\frac34\\-\frac34&\frac14\end{bmatrix}
$$
The characteristic polynomial is $$
\frac1{16}\left((13-4x)(1-4x)-9\right) = \frac1{16}\left(13-4x-52x+16x^2-9\right)=\frac{16x^2-56x+4}{16} = x^2 - \frac{7}{2}x+\frac14
$$
with roots $$
x = \frac{7/2\pm\sqrt{49/4-1}}{2} = \frac{7\pm\sqrt{45}}{4} = \frac{7\pm3\sqrt{5}}{4} 
$$
Therefore the matrix norm of $M$ is $$
||{M}||_2 = \sqrt{\frac{7+3\sqrt{5}}{4}} \approx 1.85 < 2
$$
This also implies that for $n$ sufficiently large $||{M_n(p)}||_2\le 1.9$ ("sufficiently large" may depend on $p$). Therefore, we have that $||{S_n(p)}||<  c1.9^n$ for some $c$ that depends on $p$.
Therefore, we have \begin{eqnarray}
||{\Delta_n}|| &=& ||{\begin{bmatrix}2,-1\end{bmatrix}S_{n+1}(p) - \begin{bmatrix}2,-1\end{bmatrix}S_{n}(p)}|| = ||{\begin{bmatrix}2,-1\end{bmatrix}M_nS_{n}(p) - \begin{bmatrix}2,-1\end{bmatrix}MS_{n}(p)}||\\
&\le &||{\begin{bmatrix}2,-1\end{bmatrix}}||\cdot||{M-M_n(p)}||_2||{S_n(p)}|| \le c' 1.9^n ||{M-M_n(p)}||_2
\end{eqnarray}
for some $c'$ depending on $p$. Observe that $$
||{M-M_n(p)}||_2 = ||{\begin{bmatrix} \frac32 \cdot \frac{2^{-n}p}{1-2^{-n}p}&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}}||_2 = \frac{3p}{2(2^n-p)}
$$
hence $$
||{\Delta_n}|| \le c' \frac{3p}{2(2^n-p)} 1.9^n
$$
so $||{\Delta_n}||$ goes to $0$ like $(\frac{1.9}{2})^n$. Since $\Delta_n$ goes to $0$ exponentially, this implies that $\begin{bmatrix}2,-1\end{bmatrix}S_{n}(p)$ converges to a limit.
Since $\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}2&-1\end{bmatrix}$ are independent, we conclude that $S_n(p)$ converges pointwise for each $p$. Furthermore, because $$
\begin{bmatrix}1&-1\end{bmatrix} S_n(p) \rightarrow 0
$$
we know that $S_n(p)$ converges to a matrix of the form $\begin{bmatrix}a(p)&b(p)\\a(p)&b(p)\end{bmatrix}$ for some functions $a(p)$ and $b(p)$. Therefore, the $g_0(p)$ we want satisfies $$
\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}=g_0(p) \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} S_n(p)\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} = g_0(p)\begin{bmatrix}a(p)&b(p)\\a(p)&b(p)\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix} = g_0(p)\begin{bmatrix}a(p)\\a(p)\end{bmatrix}
$$
Hence taking $g_0(p) = \frac1{a(p)}$ is the only solution. Because of how quickly $S_n(p)$ converges, one can check computationally that $a(p)$ is nonzero. (Note: This is certainly not a proof that $a(p)\ne0$ for all $p\in[\frac12,1)$, however all the values I checked work, and in fact the following theorem implies that $g(p)$ exists and therefore $a(p)$ is nonzero on this interval.)
Thus, we can define $g(p)$ by $$
g(p) = \begin{cases}
 0 & p\ge 1 \\
 \frac1{\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left(S_n(p)\right)_{11}} & p \in [\frac 1 2,1)\\
 \frac{2}{3}(1-p)g(p/2)+\frac13(1-p)g(2p) & p < \frac12
\end{cases}
$$
and this gives the unique function $g$ satisfying the three properties in the lemma. Q.E.D.
Theorem 2: Let $g(p)$ be defined as in the previous lemma. Then we have $$
f(p) = 1-g(p)
$$
Proof: Let $\tilde g(p) = 1-f(p)$. Then we have that $\tilde g$ satisfies the three conditions of the above lemma. The first two are clear. To prove the third, observe that $$
1-f(p) = P\left(\text{failure}\right) = \mathbb E \left[\prod_{n=0}^\infty (1-\min(1,Y_n))\right] =  \mathbb E \left[\prod_{n=0}^\infty (1-\min(1,2^{X_n}p))\right]
$$
Then, using DCT:$$\lim\limits_{p\rightarrow 0^+} \tilde g(p)=
\lim\limits_{p\rightarrow 0^+} 1-f(p) = \lim\limits_{p\rightarrow 0^+} \mathbb E \left[\prod_{n=0}^\infty (1-\min(1,2^{X_n}p))\right] = \mathbb E \left[\lim\limits_{p\rightarrow 0^+}\prod_{n=0}^\infty  (1-\min(1,2^{X_n}p))\right]
$$
We note that $\lim\limits_{p\rightarrow 0^+} P(Y_n <1 \text{ for all }n)=1$, and therefore we can use DCT again to bring the limit into the product as well, which gives us $\lim\limits_{p\rightarrow 0^+} 1-f(p) = 1$. Therefore $\tilde g(p)$ satisfies the conditions of Lemma 1. Q.E.D.

Q for clarification: So in fact your Theorem is a proof that $f$ is not continuously differentiable, right?

Yes, because if $f$ were continuously differentiable, then $f(p)$ would be equal to 1 everywhere.

Another Q: Why would "$Y_n$ summable a.s." imply the product $> 0$ a.s.?  I must admit I lack the background to understand this, so a reference might be what I need here.  Intuitively it would seem to me whether the product can be zero depends on the actual sum (i.e. "sum being finite" would seem to me to be insufficient).  But as I said, I might just be missing a well known lemma or two.  Thanks!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product#Convergence_criteria

@DarkMalthorp: Nice answer!

Not an answer, too long for comment
Letting $g_t$ be the probability of winning for $p=a^t$, with $a=1/2$ and $t\ \in \mathbb N$, we get the recursion (which you already basically wrote):
$$g_t=a^t+(1-a^t)\frac13 (g_{t-1} + 2 g_{t+1}) $$
with the boundary condition $g_0=1$.
This has a trivial solution $g_t=1$. What we want to find out if it has some other solution, and if it is the correct one for the problem.
For the latter, we'd need to find some bound (say , $p<\epsilon \implies g < \alpha <1$).
I didn't find a conclusive answer for neither, but numerically it seems that the alternative (and presumably correct) solution has these values
p           g
1           1
0.5         0.9288570
0.25        0.7865710
0.125       0.6087134
0.0625      0.4359375
0.03125     0.2931433
0.015625    0.1875435


Excuse me if I am missing something obvious: If your recurrence has a non-trivial solution $g^$, then wouldn't any interpolation $s g^ + (1-s) 1$ also be a solution?  E.g. $\frac{1+g^*}{2}$ would also be a non-trivial solution right?  If so, we seem to be missing some other condition, as any non-trivial solution would imply infinitely many non-trivial solutions, and then we would need some other criterion for picking the "right" one.  (Apologies if you already anticipated all this -- I didnt understand your comment about the bound so maybe that's what you mean.)

@antkam : no, because the equation is not homogeneous. You can make it homogeneus by rewriting it in terms of $h_t = 1- g_t$, so we get $h_t=(1-a^t)\frac13 (h_{t-1} + 2 h_{t+1})$ . Here your interpolation would work... but the trivial solution is now $h_t=0$

Suppose $b_t, c_t$ satisfy your recurrence.  Then $\frac{b_t + c_t}{2} = a^t + (1- a^t) \frac{1}{3} ( \frac{b_{t-1} + c_{t-1}}{2} + 2 \frac{b_{t+1} + c_{t+1}}{2})$ right?  I.e. $\frac{b_t + c_t}{2}$ also satisfies the recurrence.  I am not talking about arbitrary linear combinations.  I am talking about linear combinations where the coefficients sum to $1$ (i.e. (weighted) average, aka "mixtures")

@antkam You're right, my bad. I guess we need to add the other boundary condition $g_{\infty}=0$ (not trivial to prove).

oh i LOVE that $g_\infty = 0$ condition.  i was exactly wondering what other condition can rule out all (weighted) averages between $1$ and some (presumed to exist) $g^$, and if the latter had $g^_\infty = 0$ then that would be the perfect condition to rule out all the weighted averages.

BTW how did you "numerically" compute those numbers in the tables?  did you just simulate the actual experiment e.g. 100000 times?  i might be missing something obvious -- but i dont see a way to rewrite the recurrence so it can be solved one term after another.  (unless...  did you assume $g_t \approx 0$ for some sufficiently large $t$ and then solve the rest (precisely or iteratively) because the problem is now finite?)

@antkam The latter (I actually assumed $g_t \sim \alpha t a^t$ and estimated $\alpha$ from the previous values - rather ad-hoc, but seems to work well.
